# How to match donor data from year to year (ID Number and Associated Data)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to compare donor data from year to year and need to align them on a spreadsheet. For example, now I have the following:

Column A- shows 2013 Donors
Column B- shows 2013 Gifts
Column C- shows 2014 Donors
Column D- shows 2014 Gifts

I need to track the donors from year to year (side by side) with their gifts for each year.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

On a new sheet combine ColumnsA and C into a single column and apply to it Remove Duplicates, then look up the values from Columns B and D with something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:D,2,0),"")
```

in one column and

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:D,4,0),"")
```

in another and copy down both to suit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to be able to compare them side by side. In other words I need to be able to look across and see the 2013 donor ID, 2013 gift, 2014 donor ID, and 2014 gift side by side. I can't seem to do that with what you are suggesting.